# Output Laravel Array Key List

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following when return my variable $data;

```
{
"Test Location":
[{"name":"Kieran","round":"Test Location"},{"name":"Jordan","round":"Test Location"}],
"Location 2":
[{"name":"Paul Sample","round":"Location 2"}]
}
```

How would I output the unique key which in this example is

- Test Location
- Location 2

I've tried

```
<ul>
                    @foreach($rounds as $r => $name)
                        <li>{{ $name }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
```

But that gives me the data within the key.

Hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as:

```
<ul>
                @foreach($rounds as $r => $name)
                    <li>{{ $r }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
```

In `@foreach($rounds as $r => $name)`, `$r` is the key and `$name` is the value.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset contains`multidimensional array` so you need to iterate the dataset twice.

Try this:

```
    <ul>
        @foreach($rounds as $key => $values)
            <li>{{ $key }}</li>
            @foreach($values as $round)
                <li>
                    <strong> {{ $round['name'] }} </strong>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong> {{ $round['round'] }} </strong>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```